# would like to know how to write the functional components to class components in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getTodoList } from "./redux/action/todoList";
```

Using functional components I have written want the same how we can write in class components

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTodoList());
  }, []);

  const todoList = useSelector((state) => state.todoList);
  console.log(todoList);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {todoList.data.length > 0
        ? todoList.data.map((obj) => {
            return (
              <>
                <div className="card">
                  <div className="content">
                    <div className="header">{obj.title}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </>
            );
          })
        : ""}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect the redux store to your component, you can use [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/connect) API. As per the documentation

> The connect function takes two arguments, both optional:
>
> - mapStateToProps: called every time the store state changes. It receives the entire store state and should return an object of data this component needs.
> - mapDispatchToProps: this parameter can either be a function or an object.
>
>   - If it’s a function, it will be called once on component creation. It will receive dispatch as an argument and should return an object full of tasks that use dispatch to dispatch actions.
>   - If it’s an object full of action creators, each action creator will be turned into a prop function that automatically dispatches its action when called. Note: We recommend using this “object shorthand” form.

Your code will be changed like this.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  todoList: state.todoList
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    todoList: dispatch(getTodoList())
});

// `connect` returns a new function that accepts the component to wrap:
const connectToStore = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
// and that function returns the connected, wrapper component:
const ConnectedApp = connectToStore(App);

// We normally do both in one step, like this:
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```